# Adding multiple json fields in flask_restplus RequestParser

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I want to `expect` a request where the request.json looks like:

```
{
  "app_name": "app",
  "model_name": "model"
}
```

I created the following parser:

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('app_name', location='json', required=True)
parser.add_argument('model_name',  location='json', required=True)
```

And am using the parser as:

```
class ModelList(Resource):
    @api.expect(parser)
    def get(self):
    """Get all matching model records"""
    ....
```

This shows up in the service as:

[image]

But when I try this out, my request is translated as following:

[image]

I expect the request to look like:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5000/model" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"app_name": "test","model_name": "affinity"}'
```

and not:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5000/model" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "affinity"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, a GET request can’t have a request body, no. Only a URL is sent (and headers), so you need to put your request data into the URL (as query parameters, usually) or in headers (highly unusual, almost never a good idea). Or use POST instead of GET, but that has specific connotations in a REST API. Any reason why these parameters must be JSON?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you can send a request body even with GET request, although it is not a common practice to do so.

Comment: @MikeL: yes, technically it is legal for *any* request message to include a body, including GET, but no compliant server is going to do anything with it. Also see [HTTP GET with request body](//stackoverflow.com/q/978061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: HEAD or GET Request cannot have a body.

Refer to this SO question for why it cannot (should not) have one: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

To fix, either remove `location='json'` or specify `location='args'` instead.

```py
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('app_name', required=True)
parser.add_argument('model_name', required=True)
```

```py
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('app_name', location='args', required=True)
parser.add_argument('model_name', location='args', required=True)
```

Both will let Swagger know to send the arguments in query string and the parser know to look there.